How can I get base URL from a ServerHttpRequest?
With given instance of ServerHttpRequest, how can I get the base URL?
I'm, currently, using the following code.
ServerWebExchange exchange = ...;
ServerHttpRequest = exchange.getRequest();
URI uri = request.getURI();
URL url = uri.toURL(); // MalformedURLException
return url.getProtocol() + "://" + url.getAuthority(); // e.g. http://host:port

Do we have any intrinsic method for above method?
